# Calculating fetch

Tags: ocean-models

I am currently using a Pierson Moskowitz spectrum to model the wave energy in the Mediterranean Sea. However I don't think this this is appropriate due to the limited fetch in the coastal area that I'm interested in. Therefore I'm going to switch to a JONSWAP spectrum which will encorporate the fetch too.

I can't find many resources on how to go about calculating fetch except for the [fetchR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fetchR/vignettes/introduction-to-fetchR.html) package in R. I am not an R user (more Python/Matlab) although if this is the best option I will happily learn.

Are there any other online resources for calculating fetch in the Med sea?

Thanks,

Rachael

Comment: Would this help? https://woodshole.er.usgs.gov/project-pages/coastal_model/Tools/fetch_limited.html

Comment: can't you call R functions from Python?

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly: You have your wave model programmed in Fortran or C. You do want to calculate the fetch externally in Python or Matlab. You want to do it as it could be done with fetchR (fetch for several wind directions) for each grid cell. You want to write this fetch information out (text or netCDF) and then import it into your wave model? You do it this way to save computation time in your actual wave model?

Comment: I have significant wave height, wave direction, peak wave frequency and average spread parameters for many locations. I'm then using these to model a spectrum for each location - this is in Python (the area I'm looking at is very small, so Python is fine for the task). But you are correct, for each grid point I also want a fetch value (indeed for several directions) to input into the model too- netCDF is the preference!